# Columns in dataframe with NaN display numbers in float(default), while columns without NaN has integer as dtype(default)

Tags: python, pandas

I was taking tutorial on pandas(dataframe) and came across an example (the code is given below)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{'a':1,'c':2},{'a':3,'b':6,'c':8},{'a':78,'b':89,'c':78}])
print(df)
```

The output was:

```
    a     b   c
0   1   NaN   2
1   3   6.0   8
2  78  89.0  78
```

So only float is the datatype in the columns having NaN, while others have int as datatype by default.  Can someone provide me with an explanation for this?

Comment: because NaN can't be treated as int. but it could be treated as float. that's why pandas converts b column to float and remaining other columns as it is

Comment: Whenever you have a missing value it is taken as "NaN". and type of NaN is float . Check type(np.nan)